# FFMPEG command playing the audios all at once

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to play all the audios at a designated time frame using this command tho they all play at the  beginning of the video here is the command

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./temp/background.mp4 -itsoffset 1 -i ./temp/tts/0.mp3 -itsoffset 3 -i ./temp/tts/1.mp3 -itsoffset 4 -i ./temp/tts/10.mp3 -itsoffset 7 -i ./temp/tts/11.mp3 -itsoffset 8 -i ./temp/tts/12.mp3 -itsoffset 10 -i ./temp/tts/13.mp3 -itsoffset 12 -i ./temp/tts/14.mp3 -itsoffset 14 -i ./temp/tts/2.mp3 -itsoffset 15 -i ./temp/tts/3.mp3 -itsoffset 18 -i ./temp/tts/4.mp3 -itsoffset 20 -i ./temp/tts/5.mp3 -itsoffset 22 -i ./temp/tts/6.mp3 -itsoffset 23 -i ./temp/tts/7.mp3 -itsoffset 25 -i ./temp/tts/8.mp3 -itsoffset 27 -i ./temp/tts/9.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=5[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac ./temp/withoutsubs.mp4
```

I was expecting all the audios to play at their right time

Comment: amix doesn't sync by timestamp. Add `aresample=async=1:first_pts=0` filter for each mp3.

Comment: I did it but it didnt work ```-filter_complex aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac ./temp/withoutsubs.mp4```

Comment: You have to add filter once for each mp3 and then feed that result to amix, in the *same command*.

Comment: How would I feed it to the amix, sorry im new to ffmpeg

Comment: Is this how i add the filter? ```-aresample=async=1000:first_pts=0${time} -i ./temp/tts/${audiofile}```

Comment: Ok I think I got it, but Im getting

Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_amix_0

~~~var time = 1.75
  var command = 'ffmpeg -y -i ./temp/background.mp4'
  for (let i = 0; i < tts.length; i++) {
        let audiofile = tts[i]
        command +=  ` -af aresample=async=1000:first_pts=${time} ./temp/tts/${audiofile}`
        console.log(time)
        time += await getAudioDurationInSeconds(`./temp/tts/${audiofile}`)
}
command += 
"-filter_complex amix=inputs=5[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac ./temp/withoutsubs.mp4"
~~~

Answer (score 0):

amix doesn't sync by timestamp. You have to pad the head of each mp3 to start from timestamp 0 like this,

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i ./temp/background.mp4 \
-itsoffset 1 -i ./temp/tts/0.mp3 \
-itsoffset 3 -i ./temp/tts/1.mp3 \
-itsoffset 4 -i ./temp/tts/2.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[1]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[1a];
 [2]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[2a];
 [3]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[3a];  
 [1a][2a][3a]amix=inputs=3[a]" \
-map 0:v -map [a] \
-c:v copy -c:a aac \
./temp/withoutsubs.mp4
```